# Changing woocommerce subscription rate for existing recurring payments

Tags: woocommerce, recurring, subscriptions

We have increased the price of our subscriptions but the renewals so far are going through at the old rate although new subscribers are at the new rate.

Is there any way to make the price increase reflect in the existing subscribers recurring payments.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I found the way to do this was to modify the woocommerce database.

There are three values that need to be changed

1) In the 'wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta' table the '_line_total' value

2) In the 'wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta' table the '_line_subtotal' value
      This is based on the item id, which is looked up in the   'wp_woocommerce_order_items' table by the order number

3) In the 'wp_postmeta table', the '_order_total' value
     This is based on the order number, as shown in the subscriptions list

Some code that did this:

```
$query = "SELECT order_item_id FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items where order_id=$orderno";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query))
{
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        $itemid = $row->order_item_id;
        $itemquery = "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta where order_item_id=$itemid and meta_key='_variation_id'";
        if ($itemresult = $mysqli->query($itemquery))
        {
            $variationid = $itemresult->fetch_object()->meta_value;
           .... verify that have the right product.....
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta SET meta_value='$newamount' where order_item_id=$itemid and meta_key='_line_total'";
        $modresult = $mysqli->query($sql);

        $sql = "UPDATE wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta SET meta_value='$newamount' where order_item_id=$itemid and meta_key='_line_subtotal'";
        $modresult = $mysqli->query($sql);
    }
}


$sql = "UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='$newamount' where post_id=$orderno and meta_key='_order_total'";
printf("SQL: $sql\n", FILE_APPEND);
$modresult = $mysqli->query($sql);
printf("Update order total result:" . print_r($modresult, true)."\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Synchronize the renewal for that, or else they will get old rates

The Renewal Synchronization feature is switched off by default. To enable renewal synchronization:

Go to: **WooCommerce** > **Settings** > **Subscriptions**

Click the **Synchronize Renewals checkbox**

Click the **Save Changes** button

Read More [Here](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/renewal-synchronisation/)

Comment: Would this make all payments for a subscription go out on the same day of the month as we need them to continue recurring on the monthly anniversary of their sign-up date.

Answer (score 0):

Using the available Woo Subscriptions APIs, you can:

1. Retrieve a list of all "active" subscriptions which include products you are using.
2. Update the subscription item's prices.

This snippet will include subscriptions with products 44 and 99. It will update all subscription item's prices to $75.

```php
$product_ids = [ 44, 99 ];
$price = '75';
$subs = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_product( $product_ids, 'subscription', [
    'subscription_status' => 'active',
] );

foreach ( $subs as $sub ) {
    foreach ( $sub->get_items() as $item ) {
        wc_save_order_items( $sub->get_id(), [
            'order_item_id' => [
                $item->get_id(),
            ],
            'line_subtotal' => [
                $item->get_id() => $price,
            ],
            'line_total'    => [
                $item->get_id() => $price,
            ],
        ] );

        echo "Subscription {$sub->get_id()} price updated to {$price}. <br />";
    }
}
```

It seems to run into memory problems after about 150 items so you may limit the results to 100 and use an offset to paginate them.

```php
$subs = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_product( $product_ids, 'subscription', [
    'subscription_status' => 'active',
    'limit' => 100,
    'offset' => 0, // set to increments of 100.
] );
```

If you want to set different prices based on different products.

```php
foreach ( $subs as $sub ) {
    foreach ( $sub->get_items() as $item ) {
        switch ( $item->get_data()['product_id'] ) {
            case 44:
                $price = '64';
                break;
            case 99:
                $price = '47';
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

If you only want to change prices for payment gateways which support changing the price (e.g. ! PayPal Standard ).

```
foreach ( $subs as $sub ) {
    if ( ! \in_array( $sub->get_payment_method(), [ 'stripe', 'manual' ] ) ) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Putting it all together.

```php
$product_ids = [ 44, 99 ];
$price = '75';
$subs = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_product( $product_ids, 'subscription', [
    'subscription_status' => 'active',
    'limit' => 100,
    'offset' => 0, // set to increments of 100.
] );
foreach ( $subs as $sub ) {
    if ( ! \in_array( $sub->get_payment_method(), [ 'stripe', 'manual' ] ) ) {
        continue;
    }
    foreach ( $sub->get_items() as $item ) {
        switch ( $item->get_data()['product_id'] ) {
            case 44:
                $price = '64';
                break;
            case 99:
                $price = '47';
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }

        wc_save_order_items( $sub->get_id(), [
            'order_item_id' => [
                $item->get_id(),
            ],
            'line_subtotal' => [
                $item->get_id() => $price,
            ],
            'line_total'    => [
                $item->get_id() => $price,
            ],
        ] );

        echo "Subscription {$sub->get_id()} price updated to {$price}. <br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a `Call to undefined function wc_save_order_items()` error. Using WC 7.7.0 & WCS 5.1.2 :-(

Comment: I believe more recent version of WooCommerce filter the inclusion of the required files to "admin" location only. If you are not running this in the WP Admin, you could try adding `include_once WC_ABSPATH . 'includes/admin/class-wc-admin.php'` somewhere at the top of the script.

Comment: Thanks @mat-lipe, but that didn't work. However, I did a search and found that the `wc_save_order_items()` function is actually defined in `wc-admin-functions.php`, so changing it to that made it work. So, for completeness should anyone be looking for this in the future, you need to add `include_once WC_ABSPATH . 'includes/admin/wc-admin-functions.php';` to the top of the script. Thanks.